# How make Media query work with Ipad Pro 12.9

Tags: ios, css, ipad, media-queries

Im using the following Media query to target Ipad Pro 12.9

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

It works on the browser simulator, but when I try the actual device, the landscape view looks the same as a regular desktop. It works fine in portrait but ignores the landscape view media query.

Do you guys know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using separate media queries. One for landscape, one for portrait, one for both.

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```